# Hibernate Spatial 5 and MySQL 5.7

Tags: hibernate-5.x, hibernate-spatial, mysql-5.7

I'm using Hibernate Spatial 5.0.7 and MySQL 5.7.

I need to use MySQL ST_* precise spatial operators, in order to do that I apply MySQLSpatial56Dialect, however if I use this dialect the Geometry datatype isn't correctly retrieved from the database. This didn't happen while using a version of MySQL 5.6.

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Best to create a bug ticket for this in the Hibernate ORM issue tracker. Be sure to provide a stack trace.